# Uncaught Exception: Call to a member function have_posts() on null View

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am developing a wordpress site (ecommerce), we use Woocommerce and Sage 9 theme.
After updating php to 7.4 this issue came up.

> Uncaught Exception: Call to a member function have_posts() on null
>   (View: ...views/template-home.blade.php)

This is my code from : template-home.blade.php

```
 @php
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        @endphp

         @while($get_products->have_posts())
            @php
              $get_products->the_post();
              //global $product;
              //$product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
              //echo Casey_Pro_Helper::getvar($product);
              //do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop');
              wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
            @endphp
          @endwhile


        @php
        wp_reset_query();
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
        //woocommerce_pagination();
        do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop');

        $total = $get_products->max_num_pages;
        $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        preg_match_all('/\//', $request_uri, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        $current_page = 1;
        if (!empty($matches) && array_key_exists(1, $matches[0]) && array_key_exists(2, $matches[0])) {
            $first_slash_position = $matches[0][1][1];
            $last_slash_position = $matches[0][2][1];
            $length = strlen($request_uri) - $last_slash_position;
            $current_page = (int)substr($request_uri, $first_slash_position + 1, $length);
        }
        $base    = isset( $base ) ? $base : esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) );
        $format  = isset( $format ) ? $format : '';
        @endphp

        <nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
        @php
          echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
            'base'         => $base,
            'format'       => $format,
            'add_args'     => false,
            'current'      => max( 1, $current_page ),
            'total'        => $total,
            'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
            'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
            'type'         => 'list',
            'end_size'     => 3,
            'mid_size'     => 3,
          ) ) );
        @endphp
        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the controller : TemplateHome.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Sober\Controller\Controller;

class TemplateHome extends Controller {

    /**
     * Return news
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function GetProducts() {

        $include_ids = \App\run_equal_names_query();
        $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        preg_match_all('/\//', $request_uri, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        $page = 1;
        if (!empty($matches) && array_key_exists(1, $matches[0]) && array_key_exists(2, $matches[0])) {
            $first_slash_position = $matches[0][1][1];
            $last_slash_position = $matches[0][2][1];
            $length = strlen($request_uri) - $last_slash_position;
            $page = (int)substr($request_uri, $first_slash_position + 1, $length);
        }
        $paged = $page;
        $posts_per_page = 9;
        $offset = (($paged-1)*$posts_per_page);
        $args = [
            'ep_integrate' => false,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'post__in' => $include_ids,
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key' => '_stock',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'compare' => '>'
                ]
            ],
            'orderby' => 'modified',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        ];
        $home_products_query = new \WP_Query($args);
        return $home_products_query;
    }
```

**How can I fix this ?**

Comment: The error by itself means that the `$get_products` variable is `null` at the time when you try to call the `have_posts()` function on it. Presumably you were expecting this variable to be an instance of a class. So you need to trace why that variable is null...perhaps you never defined it, and/or never populated it. it's unclear from the code shown whether that is the case or not.

Comment: $get_products comes from the controller

Comment: check this : https://github.com/soberwp/controller#inheriting-the-treeheirarchy

Answer (score 0):

I have added these lines from the controller to my home template this is not so elegant, but now it works, what do you think how can I solve it in a more elegant way?

```html
$search_featured_image = get_field('product_placeholder_image_search','option');
$s_image = $search_featured_image['sizes']['thumbnail'];
$include_ids = \App\run_equal_names_query();
        $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        preg_match_all('/\//', $request_uri, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        $page = 1;
        if (!empty($matches) && array_key_exists(1, $matches[0]) && array_key_exists(2, $matches[0])) {
            $first_slash_position = $matches[0][1][1];
            $last_slash_position = $matches[0][2][1];
            $length = strlen($request_uri) - $last_slash_position;
            $page = (int)substr($request_uri, $first_slash_position + 1, $length);
        }
        $paged = $page;
        $posts_per_page = 9;
        $offset = (($paged-1)*$posts_per_page);
        $args = [
            'ep_integrate' => false,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'post__in' => $include_ids,
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key' => '_stock',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'compare' => '>'
                ]
            ],
            'orderby' => 'modified',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        ];

$get_products= new \WP_Query($args);
```